# Why page still stuck when rendering a large amout of data after react18 use requestIdleCallback

Tags: reactjs

As the title suggests, I am studying the principles of React 18 concurrent render mode. It is said that concurrent mode is based on requestIdleCallback and can be paused when it's time to relinquish JavaScript control, allowing the page to respond to other events or user input.

However, when I tested the code as shown below, the page still became unresponsive. Is there something that I missed in the implementation of concurrent mode?

```
const test = new Array(100000).fill(0)
  return (
    <div>
      {test.map((item, index) => (
        <h1>{index}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: It can only pause rendering in between when one component renders and the next component renders. If a single component takes a massive amount of time to render, there's nothing react can do until you return